# catboost cv producing log files

Tags: python, catboost

A number of TSV files and json files are being created when I used the cross validation CV object. I cannot find any way to prevent CV from not producing these in the documentation and end up deleting them manually. These files are obviously coming from CV (I have checked) and are named after the folds or general results such as time remaining and test scores.

Anyone know of the argument to set to turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting training the parameter `allow_writing_files` to `False`.